# Need help on Ansible issue

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I have a requirement to create the property file like below from Ansible.

```
"demo_cluster","demo_cluster_1",64,256
"demo_cluster1","demo_cluster_2",64,256
"demo_cluster2","demo_cluster_3",64,256
```

So for I have a created template file where I have defined some variables for those and will be accessing those values from the inventory file at the run time.

Template jinja2 file:

```
{{ demo_clustername }},{{ demo_cluster_1name }},{{ min }},{{ max }}
```

and I defined the value for this in the inventory file like below and it is working fine.

inventory file entries -

```
demo_clustername=demo_cluster
demo_cluster_1name=demo_cluster_2
min=64
max=256
```

Now I would like to create the multiple entries so I created jinja2 for loop but it is not working as expected.

Now the template file look like below:

```
{% for item in items %}
{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

and the modified entries like below:

```
items=["demo_cluster","demo_cluster_1",64,256]
items=["demo_cluster1","demo_cluster_2",64,256]
items=["demo_cluster2","demo_cluster_3",64,256]
```

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Now I would like to create the multiple entries so I created jinja2 for loop but it is not working as expected.

Now the template file look like below:

```
{% for item in items %}
{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

and the modified entries like below:

```
items=["demo_cluster","demo_cluster_1",64,256]
items=["demo_cluster1","demo_cluster_2",64,256]
items=["demo_cluster2","demo_cluster_3",64,256]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the variables

```yaml
  number_of_entries: 3
  name: demo_cluster
  name_: demo_cluster_
  min: 64
  max: 256
```

the template

```bash
{% for i in range(number_of_entries) %}                                             
{% if loop.first %}{% set index0='' %}                                              
{% else %}{% set index0=i %}                                                        
{% endif %}                                                                         
"{{ name }}{{ index0 }}","{{ name_ }}{{ i + 1 }}",{{ min }},{{ max }}               
{% endfor %}
```

gives

```bash
"demo_cluster","demo_cluster_1",64,256
"demo_cluster1","demo_cluster_2",64,256
"demo_cluster2","demo_cluster_3",64,256
```

You can format the line in the template

```bash
item=["{{ name }}{{ index0 }}","{{ name_ }}{{ i + 1 }}",{{ min }},{{ max }}]
```

gives

```bash
item=["demo_cluster","demo_cluster_1",64,256]
item=["demo_cluster1","demo_cluster_2",64,256]
item=["demo_cluster2","demo_cluster_3",64,256]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    number_of_entries: 3
    name: demo_cluster
    name_: demo_cluster_
    min: 64
    max: 256

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in range(number_of_entries) %}
          {% if loop.first %}{% set index0='' %}
          {% else %}{% set index0=i %}
          {% endif %}
          "{{ name }}{{ index0 }}","{{ name_ }}{{ i + 1 }}",{{ min }},{{ max }}
          {% endfor %}

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in range(number_of_entries) %}
          {% if loop.first %}{% set index0='' %}
          {% else %}{% set index0=i %}
          {% endif %}
          item=["{{ name }}{{ index0 }}","{{ name_ }}{{ i + 1 }}",{{ min }},{{ max }}]
          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks much bro.. Actually the cluster name is dynamic and can be different too like abc_cluster or it can be any name that is user defined. Also, its not only 3 lines and it can be many values or lesser that so we can't be strict to 3 bro. Could you please help with any values like below
any_cluster_name,any cluster1_name,any min value,any max value

Comment: Where do these "any values" come from?